# Encoding.GetEncoding(String)で指定可能なエンコーディング名のエイリアスを登録するには

Tags: .net

エンコーディングオブジェクトを取得する際、GetEncodingメソッド対して、以下のように「cp932」を引数として指定すると例外が発生します。
`Encoding.GetEncoding("cp932")`
※これは、「cp932」がエンコーディング名として認識されないためであり、本来は「shift_jis」や「932」「x-ms-cp932」等を指定すべきことは承知しております。

ここで、「cp932」を指定した場合でも、例外を発生させず、「shift_jis」等を指定した場合と同等のEncodingオブジェクトを取得する方法を模索しています。

「x-ms-cp932」等、本来のエンコーディング名のエイリアスとして登録されているものがあるため、何らかの方法で新たなエイリアスを登録できないかと考えていますが、良い方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cp932`をサポートする`EncodingProvider`の継承クラスを作成し、`Encoding.RegisterProvider`で登録すればよいのでは。

```
class CP932EncodingProvider : EncodingProvider
{
    public override Encoding GetEncoding(string name)
    {
        if (name.Equals("cp932", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(932);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override Encoding GetEncoding(int codepage)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(new CP932EncodingProvider());

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("cp932"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Encoding.GetEncoding()`のドキュメント](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.110).aspx)には

> The code page name of the preferred encoding. Any value returned by the WebName property is valid. Possible values are listed in the Name column of the table that appears in the Encoding class topic.

と説明されていて、[`Encoding`クラスのRmarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)にリストされている名前か`WebName`プロパティ値が有効とのことです。ですので`x-ms-cp932`は非公式な動作となります。
その上で、質問のエンコーディング登録方法としてはpgrhoさんが紹介されているように[`Encoding.RegisterProvider()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.registerprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)が提供されています。なお、この機能は.NET 4.6で導入されたものですので、4.5.2以前では使用できません。

---

参考までに`Encoding.GetEncoding()`で使用可能なエイリアスの非公式なリストを作成してみました。コードページ932に対しては`csShiftJIS`、`csWindows31J`、`ms_Kanji`、`shift-jis`、`shift_jis`、`sjis`、`x-ms-cp932`、`x-sjis`が用意されていました。
散発的に用意されているだけの印象がありますので、やはりこれらの値には依存しない方がいいと思います。

```
37: cp037, csIBM037, ebcdic-cp-ca, ebcdic-cp-nl, ebcdic-cp-us, ebcdic-cp-wt, IBM037
437: 437, cp437, csPC8CodePage437, IBM437
500: CP500, csIBM500, ebcdic-cp-be, ebcdic-cp-ch, IBM500
708: ASMO-708
720: DOS-720
737: ibm737
775: ibm775
850: cp850, IBM850
852: cp852, IBM852
855: cp855, IBM855
857: cp857, IBM857
858: CCSID00858, CP00858, cp858, IBM00858, PC-Multilingual-850+euro
860: cp860, IBM860
861: cp861, IBM861
862: cp862, DOS-862, IBM862
863: cp863, IBM863
864: cp864, IBM864
865: cp865, IBM865
866: cp866, IBM866
869: cp869, IBM869
870: CP870, csIBM870, ebcdic-cp-roece, ebcdic-cp-yu, IBM870
874: DOS-874, iso-8859-11, TIS-620, windows-874
875: cp875
932: csShiftJIS, csWindows31J, ms_Kanji, shift-jis, shift_jis, sjis, x-ms-cp932, x-sjis
936: chinese, CN-GB, csGB2312, csGB231280, csISO58GB231280, GB2312, GB2312-80, GB231280, GBK, GB_2312-80, iso-ir-58
949: csKSC56011987, iso-ir-149, korean, ks-c-5601, ks-c5601, KSC5601, KSC_5601, ks_c_5601, ks_c_5601-1987, ks_c_5601-1989, ks_c_5601_1987
950: Big5, Big5-HKSCS, cn-big5, csbig5, x-x-big5
1026: CP1026, csIBM1026, IBM1026
1047: IBM01047
1140: CCSID01140, CP01140, ebcdic-us-37+euro, IBM01140
1141: CCSID01141, CP01141, ebcdic-de-273+euro, IBM01141
1142: CCSID01142, CP01142, ebcdic-dk-277+euro, ebcdic-no-277+euro, IBM01142
1143: CCSID01143, CP01143, ebcdic-fi-278+euro, ebcdic-se-278+euro, IBM01143
1144: CCSID01144, CP01144, ebcdic-it-280+euro, IBM01144
1145: CCSID01145, CP01145, ebcdic-es-284+euro, IBM01145
1146: CCSID01146, CP01146, ebcdic-gb-285+euro, IBM01146
1147: CCSID01147, CP01147, ebcdic-fr-297+euro, IBM01147
1148: CCSID01148, CP01148, ebcdic-international-500+euro, IBM01148
1149: CCSID01149, CP01149, ebcdic-is-871+euro, IBM01149
1200: ISO-10646-UCS-2, ucs-2, unicode, utf-16, UTF-16LE
1201: unicodeFFFE, UTF-16BE
1250: windows-1250, x-cp1250
1251: windows-1251, x-cp1251
1252: windows-1252, x-ansi
1253: windows-1253
1254: Windows-1254
1255: windows-1255
1256: cp1256, windows-1256
1257: windows-1257
1258: windows-1258
1361: Johab
10000: macintosh
10001: x-mac-japanese
10002: x-mac-chinesetrad
10003: x-mac-korean
10004: x-mac-arabic
10005: x-mac-hebrew
10006: x-mac-greek
10007: x-mac-cyrillic
10008: x-mac-chinesesimp
10010: x-mac-romanian
10017: x-mac-ukrainian
10021: x-mac-thai
10029: x-mac-ce
10079: x-mac-icelandic
10081: x-mac-turkish
10082: x-mac-croatian
12000: utf-32, UTF-32LE
12001: UTF-32BE
20000: x-Chinese-CNS
20001: x-cp20001
20002: x-Chinese-Eten
20003: x-cp20003
20004: x-cp20004
20005: x-cp20005
20105: irv, x-IA5
20106: DIN_66003, German, x-IA5-German
20107: SEN_850200_B, Swedish, x-IA5-Swedish
20108: Norwegian, NS_4551-1, x-IA5-Norwegian
20127: ANSI_X3.4-1968, ANSI_X3.4-1986, ascii, cp367, csASCII, IBM367, iso-ir-6, ISO646-US, ISO_646.irv:1991, us, us-ascii
20261: x-cp20261
20269: x-cp20269
20273: CP273, csIBM273, IBM273
20277: csIBM277, EBCDIC-CP-DK, EBCDIC-CP-NO, IBM277
20278: CP278, csIBM278, ebcdic-cp-fi, ebcdic-cp-se, IBM278
20280: CP280, csIBM280, ebcdic-cp-it, IBM280
20284: CP284, csIBM284, ebcdic-cp-es, IBM284
20285: CP285, csIBM285, ebcdic-cp-gb, IBM285
20290: cp290, csIBM290, EBCDIC-JP-kana, IBM290
20297: cp297, csIBM297, ebcdic-cp-fr, IBM297
20420: cp420, csIBM420, ebcdic-cp-ar1, IBM420
20423: cp423, csIBM423, ebcdic-cp-gr, IBM423
20424: cp424, csIBM424, ebcdic-cp-he, IBM424
20833: X-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended
20838: csIBMThai, IBM-Thai
20866: csKOI8R, koi, koi8, koi8-r, koi8r
20871: CP871, csIBM871, ebcdic-cp-is, IBM871
20880: cp880, csIBM880, EBCDIC-Cyrillic, IBM880
20905: CP905, csIBM905, ebcdic-cp-tr, IBM905
20924: CCSID00924, CP00924, ebcdic-Latin9--euro, IBM00924
20936: x-cp20936
20949: x-cp20949
21025: cp1025
21866: koi8-ru, koi8-u
28591: cp819, csISOLatin1, ibm819, iso-8859-1, iso-ir-100, iso8859-1, iso_8859-1, iso_8859-1:1987, l1, latin1
28592: csISOLatin2, iso-8859-2, iso-ir-101, iso8859-2, iso_8859-2, iso_8859-2:1987, l2, latin2
28593: csISOLatin3, iso-8859-3, iso-ir-109, ISO_8859-3, ISO_8859-3:1988, l3, latin3
28594: csISOLatin4, iso-8859-4, iso-ir-110, ISO_8859-4, ISO_8859-4:1988, l4, latin4
28595: csISOLatinCyrillic, cyrillic, iso-8859-5, iso-ir-144, ISO_8859-5, ISO_8859-5:1988
28596: arabic, csISOLatinArabic, ECMA-114, iso-8859-6, iso-ir-127, ISO_8859-6, ISO_8859-6:1987
28597: csISOLatinGreek, ECMA-118, ELOT_928, greek, greek8, iso-8859-7, iso-ir-126, ISO_8859-7, ISO_8859-7:1987
28598: csISOLatinHebrew, hebrew, iso-8859-8, ISO-8859-8 Visual, iso-ir-138, ISO_8859-8, ISO_8859-8:1988, logical, visual
28599: csISOLatin5, iso-8859-9, iso-ir-148, ISO_8859-9, ISO_8859-9:1989, l5, latin5
28603: iso-8859-13
28605: csISOLatin9, iso-8859-15, ISO_8859-15, l9, latin9
29001: x-Europa
38598: iso-8859-8-i
50220: iso-2022-jp
50221: csISO2022JP
50225: csISO2022KR, iso-2022-kr, iso-2022-kr-7, iso-2022-kr-7bit
50227: cp50227, x-cp50227
51932: csEUCPkdFmtJapanese, euc-jp, Extended_UNIX_Code_Packed_Format_for_Japanese, iso-2022-jpeuc, x-euc, x-euc-jp
51936: euc-cn, x-euc-cn
51949: csEUCKR, euc-kr, iso-2022-kr-8, iso-2022-kr-8bit
52936: hz-gb-2312
54936: GB18030
57002: x-iscii-de
57003: x-iscii-be
57004: x-iscii-ta
57005: x-iscii-te
57006: x-iscii-as
57007: x-iscii-or
57008: x-iscii-ka
57009: x-iscii-ma
57010: x-iscii-gu
57011: x-iscii-pa
65000: csUnicode11UTF7, unicode-1-1-utf-7, unicode-2-0-utf-7, utf-7, x-unicode-1-1-utf-7, x-unicode-2-0-utf-7
65001: unicode-1-1-utf-8, unicode-2-0-utf-8, utf-8, x-unicode-1-1-utf-8, x-unicode-2-0-utf-8
```

取得コード（C++/CLI）

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

struct InternalEncodingDataItem {
    const char* webName;
    std::uint16_t codePage;
};

template<BindingFlags flag, class T>
inline auto invokeMember(Type^ type, String^ name, Object^ target = nullptr) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T^>(type->InvokeMember(name, flag | (target == nullptr ? BindingFlags::Static : BindingFlags::Instance) | BindingFlags::NonPublic, nullptr, target, nullptr));
}

int main() {
    auto encodingTable = Object::typeid->Assembly->GetType("System.Globalization.EncodingTable");
    auto encodingDataPtr = invokeMember<BindingFlags::GetField, Pointer>(encodingTable, "encodingDataPtr");
    auto encodingData = reinterpret_cast<InternalEncodingDataItem*>(invokeMember<BindingFlags::InvokeMethod, IntPtr>(Pointer::typeid, "GetPointerValue", encodingDataPtr)->ToPointer());
    auto lastEncodingItem = *invokeMember<BindingFlags::GetField, Int32>(encodingTable, "lastEncodingItem");
    std::multimap<std::uint16_t, const char*> encodings;
    for (auto i = 0; i <= lastEncodingItem; ++i)
        encodings.emplace(encodingData[i].codePage, encodingData[i].webName);
    for (auto it = begin(encodings); it != end(encodings);) {
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second;
        auto range = encodings.equal_range(it->first);
        while (++it != range.second)
            std::cout << ", " << it->second;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ちなみに.NET Coreだと[この辺り](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/52a816d3011f4d03b80b5940dc036b40d701f52d/src/classlibnative/nls/encodingdata.cpp#L15-L66)で`x-ms-cp932`等は消されています。